# clear the last 5 characters from a string using memset

Tags: c

I have to clear the last 5 characters from a string using memset in c;

I know only to set the first characters from a string using this function.
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "almost every programmer should know memset!";
  memset (str,'-',6);
  puts (str);
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `str[strlen(str) - 5] = 0;`

Comment: @H2CO3: Won't that just truncate the string? From her example, I think she might want to replace them with a different character (even though the title says 'clear')

Comment: @Baldrick Non sequitur. It will. And? It's irrelevant. Every function assuming a NUL-terminated string will see as if the characters were removed.

Comment: @H2CO3 It said clear the last characters specifically. Setting only the terminator will leave the characters in memory. This may be important for security reasons, therefore it is relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
char str[] = "EVERY C programmer should know memset!";
memset (&str[strlen(str) - 5],'-',5);
```

This will overwrite the last 5 characters with `-`.

Beware that the string hast to have at least 5 characters for this to work correctly.